# IPTables: Get UID of incoming network traffic

Tags: android, linux, iptables

I want to be able to log all my network traffic for all apps on Android. Currently I am using *iptables* for that purpose which generates me log messages like this:

In case of outgoing packets everything is fine and I get the uid of the sending application

```
Rule: iptables -A OUTPUT -j NFLOG
Logs: IN= OUT=pdp0 SRC=10.179.120.240 DST=173.252.102.16 LEN=52 PROTO=TCP SPT=49541 DPT=443 UID=10093
```

However, for incoming packages I only get the destination port (DPT) and there is no matching to receiving apps.

```
Rule: iptables -A INPUT -j NFLOG
Logs: IN=pdp0 OUT= SRC=173.252.102.16 DST=10.179.120.240 LEN=81 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=49541
```

Is that something *iptables* can cover? If not, how can I get the App that receives a packet over network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic passes iptables before it end up in local processing by daemons/servers/..., so iptables does not know the owner (UID) of a packet in INPUT chains.
See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

Comment: Thank you, this answers the first part of my question! Anyway, is there an easy way to map the ports of incoming packets to an application?

Answer (score 0):

To get an application list you could generate a list of applications dynamicly using *netstat -tulpen* or *ss -tulpen* and link that data with with your iptables logs from INPUT chains.